# NTP without DNS

Tags: dns, ntp

I have a box running ubuntu 10.04 x86 & it's isolated by necessity from a lot of the network.
It is blocked from DNS.

I'd like it to keep accurate time, so I've configured NTP with several servers, all IP addresses. It's got the IP address, so it won't need to do DNS lookups, riiiight?

Here's the error I get when I try to update time:

date before sync:

```
Fri May 20 08:03:32 PDT 2016
* Stopping NTP server ntpd
...done.
Name server cannot be used, exiting20 May 08:03:32 ntpdate[26887]: name server cannot be used, reason: Temporary failure in name resolution

* Starting NTP server ntpd
...done.
COMMAND FAILED: /usr/sbin/ntpdate -u 216.228.192.69 prefer #S2Platform-Server1 131.107.13.100 prefer #S2Platform-Server2 192.43.244.18 prefer #S2Platform-Server3
date after sync:
Fri May 20 08:03:32 PDT 2016
Sync failed
```

My question: is this ever going to work or does NTP just flat-out require DNS?
I've done a lot of googling but I can't find any info about this.

Thank you

I've also asked this question on the forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested `ntpdate` which is the command that is failing using query mode.  It works fine.  The failure appears to be related to the values like `#S2Platform-Server1` which do require DNS resolution.  It appears you may have commented out servers in `/etc/ntp.conf` or `/etc/default/ntpdate` incorrectly.  The comment needs to be at the beginning of the line.

The name resolution issue is likely due to the invalid names rather than lack of DNS.  You can disable DNS resolution in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and it won't be attempted by resolver calls.